# Is there a rarely known rule about Pawns eating indirectly?

Tags: rules, pawns, chess.com

The game analysis tool of chess.com tells me I should have done a move which looks impossible to me.

[image: how the situation looked]
[image: what the game tells me]

Obviously my move, e1, was very stupid. But what the game tells me seems impossible. Is it a bug? If so, what would have been the actual best move?

Comment: It is a well known rule, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/En_passant.

Comment: Damn. Definitely not well known with chess noobs like me. Thank you for enlightening me!